# adding Moodle Manual self completion

Tags: moodle

I'm looking for any Moodle developers/hackers/administrators to help me with this issue (more of a witch hunt than anything).

I have about 300 courses that I need to add a manual self completion to, as well as a self completion block.

I think I've got the block code figured out:

```
insert into mdl2_block_instances (blockname, parentcontextid, showinsubcontexts, pagetypepattern, defaultregion, defaultweight) values ('selfcompletion', $contextid, 0, 'course-view-*', 'side-post', 5)
```

I still don't know which table field to change the manual self completion to true and the I'm getting tired of staring at the Moodle schema.  Would anyone have the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable manual self completion criteria in course execute the following query.

```
INSERT INTO  prefix_course_completion_criteria (course,criteriatype) VALUES(courseid,1);
```

I think it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Yep.  The other one was block_instances after doing some more hunting.